# Calculate object values with a filter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have a question connected with calculating JS object values with a filter. e.g I want to calculate sum of final_amount-s depend on a country_name.

```
[
   {
      "id":3,
      "country_name":"USA",
      "final_amount":0
   },
   {
      "id":7,
      "country_name":"Canada",
      "final_amount":2500
   },
   {
      "id":9,
      "country_name":"Canada",
      "final_amount":2000
   }
]
```

So in this example I want to achieve to the result of Something like this.

```
[
   {
      "country_name":"USA",
      "final_amount":0
   },
   {
      "country_name":"Canada",
      "final_amount":4500
   }
]
```

Comment: [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: oh not. i can't write new answer. so, you can see my solution at [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@saoxa37/WornInconsequentialPrograms#index.js)

Comment: thank you very much dear Minh Viet, that helped me.